# What is the MTMSREE PowerPC op?

Tags: assembly, powerpc

I'm looking at a core dump of a (Xenon) PowerPC executable compiled with MSVC. The function I'm debugging has an op that the MSVC disassembler calls `mtmsree r13`. `mtmsree` isn't in the IBM docs for the PPC; what does this op do?

It immediately follows a `mfmsr` and obviously it's moving something to the machine state register, but I don't know what that `ee` suffix is supposed to mean. It must be some sort of cutesy Microsoft nickname for an op the PPC docs call something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instruction is an extended form of the mtmsrd instruction that has the L bit set (0x00010000).  Instead of modifying the entire MSR, it only modifies the EE (External interrupt Enable) and RI (Recoverable Interrupt) btis.  It is faster than mtmsrd L=0 as it execution synchronizing instead of context synchronizing.  It is a priviledged instruction so will cause an exception to the os, and is .: still slow.

There is public documentation for this in IBM's Book III: PowerPC Operating Environment Architecture v2.02 (page 91), http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/power/library/pa-archguidev2/?S_TACT=105AGX16&S_CMP=LP

- Luke H

Answer (score 0):

I picked apart the machine code for the instruction ( `011111 01101 00001 00000 0010110010 0` ) and it turns out that `mtmsree` is what everyone else just calls `mtmsrd`.

Answer (score 0):

Bits 21:30 of the mtmsr instruction are 0010010010, not 0010110010.

My guess is that mtmsree is a Xenon-specific instruction that sets only the EE bit in the MSR.  The Book E machines have the wrtee and wrteei instructions to do that.  I wish I knew where to find a PEM for Xenon.

Comment: My bad -- 0010110010 is mtmsrd, not mtmsr (that is, the 64-bit version). But if you search for mtmsrd in the IBM docs it just takes you to MTMSR.

Comment: The relevant PEM, so far as I can tell, is just IBM's "PowerPC Microprocessor Family: Programming Environments Manual for 64 and 32-Bit Microprocessors." But MSFT loves to invent its own quirky little codenames for things.